# How to observe ViewModel LiveData changes from Compose state holder class?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am following the Android Developers Managing State in Compose guide.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#managing-state

I have implemented my own state holder which takes the viewModel as parameter as per diagram below. Inside the state holder I have State objects like `mutableStateOf()` which trigger re-composition.

The issue I am having is how to have `MyStateHolder` observe changes to `LiveData` in `MyViewModel`. As `MyStateHolder` is a POJO, I cannot use features such as `observeAsState()`.

It seems odd that google recommend this approach but provide no out of the box way to do this.

How can I observe changes from viewModel in state holder? Am I missing something?

[image: Jetpack Compose Managing State Architecture]

```
class MyStateHolder(
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel,
) {
    //initialise state variables and observe _portfolioData
    var portfolioDataMap = mutableStateMapOf<String, PortfolioDataModel>().apply {
        putAll(viewModel.portfolioData.value!!)
        viewModel.portfolioData.observeAsState() /*error here: cannot observeAsState in POJO*/
    }
}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _portfolioData: MutableLiveData<Map<String, PortfolioDataModel>> =
        MutableLiveData()
    val portfolioData: LiveData<Map<String, PortfolioDataModel>>
        get() = _portfolioData

    fun setStateEvent(mainStateEvent: MainStateEvent<String>) {
        //send events to update _portfolioData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing life model requires a lifecycle owner. You can add this parameter to your state holder:

```kotlin
class MyStateHolder(
    private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel,
) {
    //initialise state variables and observe _portfolioData
    var portfolioDataMap = mutableStateMapOf<String, PortfolioDataModel>().apply {
        putAll(viewModel.portfolioData.value!!)
    }

    init {
        viewModel.portfolioData.observe(lifecycleOwner) {
            portfolioDataMap.clear()
            portfolioDataMap.putAll(it)
        }
    }
}
```

And during initialization you can pass it from `LocalLifecycleOwner.current`, basically like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberMyStateHolder() : MyStateHolder {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val viewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()
    // consider using rememberSaveable instead of remember with a custom saver
    // in case of configuration change, e.g. screen rotation
    return remember(lifecycleOwner, viewModel) {
        MyStateHolder(lifecycleOwner, viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. It looks like the observer also helps to initiate my UI on launch. I was hoping I could remove the `.apply {putAll(viewModel.portfolioData.value!!)}` when declaring  `portfolioDataMap` to simplify the code. However when I do this it takes a couple of seconds longer for my UI to show. what would be your recommendation?

Comment: @mairs8 not sure, [here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/54e40f4daed55d80d94b6dbb3abab64b) is my full example, and first `observe` is getting called in 0.02 seconds after init.